# Plotting surface of a subset of 2d matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have this function to plot a 2d matrix with surf. User is allowed to specify the subset of the matrix.

```
function surf_sub(file,row,col1,col2)
% Plot submatrix read in from a file
% number of rows/columns can be specified

    m=dlmread(file,','); 
    if nargin < 3
        n=m(1:row,:);
        figure;
        surf(1:row,:,n);
    else
        n=m(1:row,col1:col2);
        figure;
        surf(1:row,col1:col2,n)
    end


end
```

Number of columns is unknown. So if the range of column is not specified, I wanted to plot all the columns. Apparently having ":" to represent all cols is not allowed and thus the following error. What is the right way to do it?

> At compilation, "surf" was determined to be a variable and this
>   variable is uninitialized. "surf" is also a function name and previous
>   versions of MATLAB would have called the function. However, MATLAB 7
>   forbids the use of the same name in the same context as both a
>   function and a variable.
>
> Error in surf_sub (line 9)
>           surf(1:row,:,n);

Comment: What's wrong with `surf(n)`?

Comment: or with `surf(your_matrix(rows,cols))` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont understand why you insist on the inputs `col1`, `col2` and not just one variable instead called `cols`, but whatever. As per your question:

```
function surf_sub(file,row,col1,col2)

m=dlmread(file,','); 
if nargin < 3
    n=m(1:row,:);
    figure;
    surf(n(1:row,:));
else
    figure;
    surf(n(1:row,col1:col2))
end
```

Should do.

If I had to do this I would just write:

```
surf(n(rows,cols));
```

with input such as, `rows=1:30`, `cols=1:size(n,1)` etc...